# Limit points of a set and deleted neighborhood of $S=(- \infty, -1] \cup (1,2) \cup \{3\} $

Tags: real-analysis

> Quoting an example:
>
> Let $S=(- \infty, -1] \cup (1,2) \cup \{3\} $,
>
> then the set of limit points are $(- \infty, -1] \cup [1,2]$

Also the book gives this definition: "$x_0$ is a limit point of S if every *deleted neighborhood* of $x_0$ contains a point of $S$"

I m new to this, I am not really understanding the notion "deleted neighborhood", also why $\{3\}$ is not considered a limit point.

Any input is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ is a set of the type $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x_0\}$, for some $\varepsilon>0$.

The point $3$ is not a limit point because $\bigl((3-1,3+1)\setminus\{3\}\bigr)\cap S=\emptyset$. So, there is a deleted neighborhood of $3$ with no point of $S$.

Comment: Thx for the input,

Comment: I understood $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$  is a neighborhood  of $x_0$, What does  the symbol " \ " signify in between? particularly in $ ((3-1,3+1)\{3}) \cap S = 0$ ?

Comment: It means “minus”. So, $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x_0\}=(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0)\cup(x_0,x_0+\varepsilon)$.